# Excel VBA - Getting "Object Required" Error When Stating Range Is Not Null

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

Below is my code where I'm getting the error.  I've marked the line that the error occurs on in bold (i.e. ** at the beginning and end of the line **).

The specific part of the code I'm receiving the error on is: **And (Range("M5:M78") Is Not Null)**

If a range is an object, why cannot I not state that this range (above) Is Not Null?

```
Option Explicit

Sub ResetWorksheetMonth1()

Dim i As Long

Dim LastRow As Long

LastRow = Range("X" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

With Worksheets("Analysis Worksheet").Activate

For i = 5 To LastRow

**If Range("M" & i).Value = 0 And (Range("M5:M78") Is Not Null) And Range("N" & i).Value > 0 And Range("O" & i).Value > 0 And Range("P" & i).Value > 0 _
    And Range("Q" & i).Value > 0 And Range("R" & i).Value > 0 And Range("S" & i).Value > 0 And Range("T" & i).Value > 0 _
    And Range("U" & i).Value > 0 And Range("V" & i).Value > 0 And Range("W" & i).Value > 0 And Range("X" & i).Value > 0 Then**

Range("M" & i).Value = Range("N" & i).Value

Range("N" & i).Value = Range("O" & i).Value

Range("O" & i).Value = Range("P" & i).Value

Range("P" & i).Value = Range("Q" & i).Value

Range("Q" & i).Value = Range("R" & i).Value

Range("R" & i).Value = Range("S" & i).Value

Range("S" & i).Value = Range("T" & i).Value

Range("T" & i).Value = Range("U" & i).Value

Range("U" & i).Value = Range("V" & i).Value

Range("V" & i).Value = Range("W" & i).Value

Range("W" & i).Value = Range("X" & i).Value

Range("X" & i).Value = Range("Z" & i).Value

Range("Y" & i).Formula = "=SUM(" & Range(Cells(i, 13), Cells(i, 24)).Address(False, False) & ")"

Range("Z" & i).Value = Null

Range("AL" & i).Formula = "=SUM(" & Range(Cells(i, 26), Cells(i, 37)).Address(False, False) & ")"

End If

Next i
```

Comment: Was able to figure it out.  I'm used to programming in SQL (SQL Server specifically), so I'm not as familiar with VBA.  Was able to get my code to work by using `And Not IsEmpty(Range("M" & i).Value)` at the end of the If statement.

Answer (score 0):

If you're just trying to check that all cells in that range are empty, you can use

```
WorksheetFunction.CountA(Range("M5:M78")) <> 0
```

Bear in mind that what you're trying is going to check if a whole range is equal to null, not loop through and check the contents of each cell in that range.